# How to repeatedly instantiate an object in a do-while loop?

Tags: java, instantiation

I'm writing a Battleship clone in Java. I have a standard Ship class, which has a constructor that takes input from the user.

The ship has a boolean field, valid, which is calculated after the ship object's constructed.

I want to keep instantiating the Ship until it's valid, but the compiler throws me a "cannot find symbol (patrolBoats)".  Why? How do I get around this?

```
do {
    Ship patrolBoat = new Ship(2, "Patrol Boat", promptInputForEnds("Patrol Boat", 2, kboard));
} while (patrolBoat.valid);
```

Comment: Is it a scope issue?

Comment: Not the issue, but do you mean `while (!patrolBoat.valid)`? Looks like you're trying to create *invalid* instances here.

Comment: It's not usually considered good design to have the ability to create invalid objects. Better to have a factory method that validates its parameters and only creates objects if the parameters are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're declaring the `patrolBoat` variable inside the loop, so it's not in the scope of the `while` statement.

Declare `Ship patrolBoat` before the loop:

```
Ship patrolBoat;
do {
  patrolBoat = ...
} while (patrolBoat.valid);
```